# How to prove the inequality $(1+\frac{1}{k(k+1)})^k \geq 1+\frac{1}{k+1}$

Tags: calculus, inequality

Is inequality $$\Big  (1+\frac{1}{k(k+1)}\Big )^k \geq 1+\frac{1}{k+1}$$ is true for all $k \in  \mathbb{N}$ ? I am proving this using binomial theorem on the right side but I don't know what to do in the middle since there are many terms and there is an exponent of $k$. Is there a better way to prove this one? Thanks. I think of using $AM \geq GM$ inequality but I don't know how to apply it.Thanks Again.

Comment: Check small cases, is the sign correct?

Comment: @CalvinLin: I found out that my previous question with $k+1$ in the denominator the inequality $\leq$ should have been $\geq$. It should have been $k+2$ as I edited a while ago..In this particular case I do not know anymore if the inequality $\geq$ be $\leq$.

Comment: ok, my bad..so i will edit this one and return it to my original question? then make a new one?

Comment: @ Calvin Lin: Thanks a lot

Comment: I have edited the inequality sign so that the statements are now true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\left(1+\frac{1}{k(k+1)}\right)^k=\sum_{i=0}^k{k\choose i}\frac{1}{(k(k+1))^i}=1+\frac{1}{k+1}+\text{ something nonnegative} \ge 1+\frac{1}{k+1}.
$$

Comment: Thanks Mercy.. Sorry, I was just overthinking the problem. I never consider when $i=1$.. thanks2s

Comment: You're welcome. Btw it's $LHS \ge RHS$, and not $LHS \le RHS$ as you wrote!

Comment: OMG, the inequality I was solving was that the $k+1$ in the LHS should have been $k+2$

Comment: In my initial problem, if its $k+1$, then $LHS \geq RHS$. what if it is $k+2$? will it still be $LHS \geq RHS$? Sorry for the changes in the question. @Mercy..

Comment: That changes everything !

Comment: the binomial theorem is not anymore useful in this case, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** Bernoulli inequality and see Calvin`s comment......

You need the stronger version of Bernoulli, namely the one which says "*with equality if and only if...*"

Comment: @ N.S.: the bernoulli inequality is that the the expression with the exponent is greater than that of the expression without the exponent. In my problem, the one with the exponent is lesser than the one without.. How can I use the  Bernoulli inequality? thanks2x

Comment: @KenethAdrian Yes, the bernoulli inequality proves that LHS > RHS. Which means that the sign in your inequality is WRONG.

Answer (score 0):

First, note that $$f(x)=\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x$$ is a strictly increasing function on $(0,+\infty)$, by taking its derivative, which is $$\frac{(1+1/x)^x(-1+(1+x)\ln (1+1/x))}{1+x}$$

Hence, $f(k(k+1))>f(k+1)$.  Now, take the $(k+1)$-th root of each side and you're done.